# Besides Stephen King himself, what actor has appeared in the most Stephen King supernatural film/TV adaptions and/or audio works?

Tags: actors, stephen-king

I was watching [The Green Mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Mile_(film)) the other day and noticed an actor that seemed familiar from another Stephen King movie, [Jeffrey DeMunn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_DeMunn). I had also remembered DeMunn from a Stephen King audio book several years back.

In addition to the Green Mile I remember seeing DeMunn in [The Storm of the Century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_of_the_Century) and [The Mist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mist_(film).). The audiobooks I remember DeMunn narrating were [The DreamCatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreamcatcher_(novel)) and [The Colorado Kid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Colorado_Kid). Though I could not find any link between DeMunn and the TV series Haven which was based on the Colorado Kid.

At five listings this is pretty impressive considering the only other actors I can think of off-hand that had multiple roles in Stephen King Movies are Martin Sheen [Firestarter](https://www.google.com/search?q=wiki%20firestarter%20movie&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gws_rd=ssl) and The Dead Zone [The Dead Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dead_Zone_(film)) and Miguel Ferrer in [The Night Flier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Flier_(film)) and [The Stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stand_(miniseries)). Stephen King himself has only had 10 appearances per his the Wiki [Stephen King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleepwalkers_(film)) site.

Note, to keep this within the realm of this site, only supernatural/SF King works qualify. E.g. such as the Mist and Storm of the Century.  Films such as Shawshank Redemption do not.

Are there any other actors (don't have to be famous) that have more than 5 appearances? More than 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an actor, but since you include audiobooks:

### Frank Muller – 7 (+3) appearances

- Black House (audiobook)
- The Breathing Method (audiobook)
- The Dark Tower: The Drawing of the Three (audiobook)
- The Dark Tower: The Waste Lands (audiobook)
- The Dark Tower: Wizard and Glass (audiobook)
- The Green Mile (audiobook)
- The Talisman (audiobook)

Non-competing (not speculative fiction):

- Apt Pupil (audiobook)
- The Body (audiobook)
- The Shawshank Redemption (audiobook)

In case you don't think this is eligible, I can at least offer another actor with 5 appearances:

### William MacDonald – 5 appearances

- The X Files: Chinga (1993)
- The Dead Zone (2002)
- Kingdom Hospital (2004)
- Haven (2010)
- Carrie (2013)

Including the names from beichst and Ben Cannon, this means there are four actors with 5 appearances each: Matt Frewer, Cynthia Garris, Steven Weber and William MacDonald. Jeffrey DeMunn does not count, in my opinion, since *The Colorado Kid* is not supernatural.

Furhermore there are a couple of actors which also have five appearances, but one of them each is in a non-supernatural story: Brian Libby, Mick Garris, Kathy Bates, Bruce Davison, Frances Sternhagen

Comment: After some further review, good call on DeMunn.  I had only seen the Haven version of Colorado Kid, not the book. I assumed the  Colorado Kid itself was also supernatural. Reading more about it, I can see that it was not.  Too, I did want to include audio book reads, I think we have a winner with Frank Muller.  Thanks for the research.

Comment: Just an addendum in case people didn't know: Frank Muller also read the audiobook of the original (non-revised) version of The Dark Tower: The Gunslinger, which puts him at 8 (+3) appearances.

I'm not aware of any legal way to procure this recording, however (and it's not even listed on StephenKing.com), but it does exist.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Frewer or the minor roles of Cynthia Garris (Director Mick Garris' Wife) according to this:

http://filmverse.com/2011/11/25/stephen-kings-1-fans/

Although some of these are straight horror, even King's horror often contained a supernatural element, however small. The article is 2011, but on a quick scan of cast lists I don't find any major shakeups since then. Also of note is that Steven Weber voiced an audiobook of IT to add to the acting credits mentioned in the filmverse article.

http://stephenking.com/library/audiobook/

Comment: Great find!  If we are counting the audio roles (which I indicated we would) that actually puts Steven Weber at five which ties him with Matt Frewer and Cynthia Garris as well as Jeffrey DeMunn (as Jeffrey has three supernatural films and two audiobooks).  That would be an interesting 4-way tie of 5 items each.

Answer (score -2):

What about Kathy Bates ??? I know she is in a bunch of Stephen King movies too. The stand, the Misery, Dolores Claiborne, I believe she has done audio for books too, not sure of more.... but you cant fail to notice her, she is an amazing actor

Comment: Can you provide a number she's been in, whether it's any more than the others stated?